# Why can't VSCode open files from Explorer if it was open as administrator?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I set VSCode to open as administrator on the shortcut settings.

This causes a weird behaviour in which VSCode can't open other files from Explorer just returning that Windows error sound and no message at all. Doesn't open on neither same nor new instance.

But if I go through `File / Open`, it works.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I just realised that Explorer won't open things as administrator and that's why it won't open in that instance

Still, I think VSCode should be able to open a new non-admin instance.

For anybody else looking for this in the future, the work around would be to force it to always open as admin, so Explorer won't have an option. To do that, go to the .exe, right click, Properties, Compatibility, check "Run this program as admin" (might be differently worded. My system isn't in English).

With this, it will always open, but won't create a new instance